# Fit histogram log scale python

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram, curve-fitting, logarithm

I need to fit a curve with my histogram in python. I did this before with normal histograms, this time I am trying to do the same with a logarithmic plot in x.
This is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

//radius is my np.array
Rmin = min(radius)
Rmax = max(radius)
logmin = np.log(Rmin)
logmax = np.log(Rmax)
bins = 10**(np.arange(logmin,logmax,0.1))
plt.figure()
plt.xscale("log")
plt.hist(radius, bins, color = 'red')
plt.show()
```

This is showing a gaussian distribution. I am trying to fit a curve with it and what I did is computing the following before the show() command.

```
(mu, sigma) = np.log(norm.fit((radius)))
y = (mlab.normpdf(np.log(bins), mu, sigma))
plt.plot(bins, y, 'b--', linewidth=2)
```

My result is a very flattened curve with respect to my distribution.
Can someone help me?

I can not add the whole array r(50000 points), therefore I have added a picture showing my result. [See image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5nidD.png)

Comment: At the moment the issue is not reproducible. See [mcve]. Please edit your question to include such example.

Comment: I have added a picture.